# Node.js forEach: cannot read property '[object Array]' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, foreach

I've never seen this one before. This error occurred on both Node.js 6.3.0 and 6.9.1 LTS, which I updated to in an effort to resolve this.

I'm trying to build stats for a game based on some data I have, not particularly important. What is important is that the following function, part of my Game class, fails:

```
computeStats() {
  var stats
    , roster
    , team, opp, scoreState, oppScoreState
    , TOI = this.calculateTOIData()
    , eventCounter = this.calculateEventData()

  [['home', 'away'], ['away', 'home']].forEach((teams) => { //this is line 74 / error source
    team = teams[0];
    opp = teams[1];

    roster = this[team].roster;

    stats = {
      //some assignments occur here from my TOI and eventCounter objects
    }

    this.setStats(team, stats);
  })
}
```

The error thrown is

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '[object Array]' of undefined
    at GameTracker.computeStats (/Users/nawgszy/repo/lib/Game.js:74:5)
    at new GameTracker (/Users/nawgszy/repo/lib/Game.js:39:10)
```

I have no idea how this is possible. The array is hard-coded, right there. Any ideas? I can work around it, but I find this specific structure to be the easiest way to generate stats like I want to use.

Comment: I have no errors here. Can you update your post with full code?

Comment: Is it really the full code you're sharing? This works OK on chrome...: [['home', 'away'], ['away', 'home']].forEach((teams) => { console.log(teams)});

Comment: another notice - you have 2 different `team` vars...

Comment: what version of node are you using?  there's definitely no problem with forEach, see this: https://runkit.com/skhavari/40539854

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the ASI that is messing with you I guess. Add a semicolon after `eventCounter = this.calculateEventData()` and see how it runs.

more info : http://benalman.com/news/2013/01/advice-javascript-semicolon-haters/

Comment: Beautiful, thanks. I guess that's a flaw with my style of writing my variables, will have to be careful with that in the future.

Comment: yea, you probably seen lots of js like `;(function(){..})()` or `;[1,2,3].forEach..`

Answer (score 2):

The missing semi-colon after `this.calculateEventData()`
is causing the following bracket notation to behave as a subscript access, instead of in-place array notation.

The code reads as:

```
var eventCounter = (this.calculateEventData()[['home', 'away'], ['away', 'home']]).forEach((teams) => { ... });
```

Note the parenthesis I've added. The [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) causes `['away', 'home']` to be the subscript, which gets passed through `Object.prototype.toString()`, becoming `'[object Array]'`.

`this.calculateEventData()` returns `undefined`. The statements becomes `undefined['[object Array]']`.

Basically, use semi-colons, and maybe avoid inline arrays (or prefix them with a semi-colon, because that's safe).

```
var stats
   , roster
   , team, opp, scoreState, oppScoreState
   , TOI = this.calculateTOIData()
   , eventCounter = this.calculateEventData(); // <-- Right there.
```

---

A minimal reproduction:

```
// test.js
const func = () => {};

const result = func()
[[]].forEach(() => {});
```

Running with Node.js. Will also fail in the [browser](https://jsfiddle.net/9c7apc8o/).

```
$ node -v
v6.5.0
$ node test.js
/home/foo/test.js:4
[[]].forEach(() => {});
^

TypeError: Cannot read property '[object Array]' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/foo/test.js:4:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:590:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

Comment: This is a great answer, I accepted the other one first but maybe I chose rashly. Thanks for the help and the clear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that what you showed as `[['home', 'away'], ['away', 'home']]` there is actually a variable; and that variable is undefined ( possibly mistyped or undeclared )

Answer (score 0):

I think @Oka has worked out the error you are seeing.

However, it looks like have another issue where you are indexing into an object with a string **array** instead of a string **value**:

```
(teams) => {
    // teams: string[][];

    team = teams[0];    // team: string[];
    opp = teams[1];     // opp: string[];

    // Issue here: Trying to index `this[team]` with a string array, not a string value.
    roster = this[team].roster;

    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the shoutout, but I believe you're slightly mistaken. `teams` is a `string[]` - `team` is a `string`. `[['foo', 'bar'], ['bar', 'foo']].forEach((array) => console.log(typeof array[0]))` --> (2) string

Comment: As Oka said, I'm iterating over the two-dimensional array, so `teams` is, at every point, a `string[]`, and thus `teams[i]` is a `string`. It works now that I put in a semicolon as suggested!